# Does python HAVE to be case sensitive?

Tags: python, input, uppercase, lowercase

When a user inputs a command using:

```
input()
```

Is it possible within python to make it so that **the case** in which they enter the command **does not** matter?

eg:

```
print("Do you Shout? Look? Continue?")
action1 = input()
if action1 == "Continue":
```

Can I make it so that if they enter "continue" (in lower case) this section of code will still work? Thanks in advance for responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest sticking with a single case when checking. So you should use "continue". Keep it all using a single case (in this case lower case), by using either [lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) or [upper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to control the casing, to ensure your conditions are matched exactly as you expect.

```
print("Do you Shout? Look? Continue?")
action1 = input()
if action1.lower() == "continue":
    # do things
```